# Trying to target only frontpage collection to apply a style(Shopify)

Tags: shopify, liquid

OK, so I had asked a few weeks ago on the Shopify forum(slow responses) how to target just one product on a collection page so that there is no hover affect, but now I only want to target the frontpage collection and not my many other collection pages on the site. 
Theme is Masonry and here is a snipet of the code I'm working with:

```
{% if settings.prod_block_display  contains 'hover' %}
  {% unless forloop.index == 1%}
  <div class="hoverinfo{% if forloop.index == 1 %}no-overlay {% endif %}"> 
    <a href="{{ product_url }}">
      <div class="info-box">
      <div class="title">{{ product-block.title }}</div>
      <div class="price">
        {% if product-block.compare_at_price_max > product-block.price %}
        <span class="previously">{{ product-block.compare_at_price_max | money }}</span>
        {% endif %}

        {% if product-block.price_varies %}<span class="from">{{ 'products.listing.from' | t }}</span>{% endif %}
        <span class="actual">{{ product-block.price | money }}</span>
      </div>
      </div>
        </a>
  </div>
  {% endunless %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if settings.prod_block_qv and no_quick_buy == false %}
  {% unless forloop.index == 1 %}
  <div class="quick-buy-row{% if forloop.index == 1%}no-overlay {% endif %}">
    <a href="#" class="quick-buy button">{{ 'products.listing.quick_view' | t }}</a>
  </div>
  {% endunless %}
  {% endif %}
```

The "{% unless forloop.index == 1%}
       " codes are the effects I only want to apply to the frontpage. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can add `{{ collection.handle }}` to classes of product `div`s where you want to apply the effect. Then in **`styles.css.liquid`** add a style for the collection handle (`collection.handle`) class as required.

Comment: that's what I assume would be the way to go if you just consider the title. The solution doesn't really go with the code sample though. To add on to this there are also possibilities like `{{collection.handle}}-show` and `{{collection.handle}}-hide`

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

What @HymnZ was trying to point to was that you can do things like in styles.liquid.css:

```
.frontpage .hoverinfo{
    display:none;
}
```

and then in your template:

```
<div class="{{collection.handle}}">
    <div class="hoverinfo">
       ...
    </div>
 </div>
```

This is the easiest way to use this strategy. What I was trying to add on was that you can potentially also use prefixes and suffixes on classes that concatenate with handles to offer more functionality. In styles:

```
.hide{
    display:none;
 }

 .frontpage-show{
    display:block;
}
```

and then in your template:

```
<div class="hide {{collection.handle}}-show">
```

Since most browsers support stacked selectors you probably don't need the -hide, -show variants but they can be helpful depending on how your mind works these things out. The sample above can be used to show/hide things for a variety of circumstances. e.g. you could target elements for a variety of collections:

```
.frontpage-show,
.collection1-show,
.frontpage.hide, /* these second two are the stacked equivalents to the -show variants */
.collection1.hide{
    display:block;
}
```

Of course you can also do much of this in liquid itself:

```
{% assign showFor = "frontpage,collection1" |split ','%}
{% if showFor contains collection.handle %}
  <div>Something limited</div>
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% assign showFor = "frontpage,collection1" |split ','%}
  <div class="{% if showFor contains collection.handle %}conditional{% endif %}">
    Something limited
  </div>
```

Comment: EDIT: mm, I tried everything and the no-hover on the first product is still applying to the other collections. :(

Comment: it's hard to say exactly what your problem is. Are you wanting help debugging the sample you provided? It's out of context (we have to assume you are looping on a collection's products) but it has at least two significant errors. -- Your liquid code only executes when the forloop.index is not 1 and inside that you have some liquid that only executes when the forloop.index is equal to 1 so it will never run. Also if it did run it doesn't look like it would work - you'd end up with a class 'hoverinfono-overlay'. If those are meant to be two classes you need a space somewhere in your code.

Comment: OK, maybe I didn't explain it well...the code I posted is one I tweaked when I asked for some help on how to remove the hover over style on a product image. What I'm trying to figure out is how to isolate that code so it only works on the frontpage collection. Does that make sense??

Comment: So any of the suggestions would work. For instance replace `{% unless forloop.index == 1%}` with `{% if collection.handle == 'frontpage' %}` and replace the `endunless` with `endif`

Comment: It's till not working. :( Now I just have EVERY product on all collection not showing the hover....

Comment: @KatMoniz Which page is this code snippet exactly from? home page or collection page or some other page?

Comment: it's from the product-block-list page

Comment: Do you have a site we could look at?